# Powershell function to replace or add lines in text files

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, append

I'm working on a powershell script that modifies config files. I have files like this:

```
#####################################################
# comment about logentrytimeout
#####################################################
Logentrytimeout= 1800
```

who should look like this:

```
#####################################################
# comment about logentrytimeout
#####################################################
Logentrytimeout= 180
disablepostprocessing = 1
segmentstarttimeout = 180
```

If there is a key set(Logentrytimeout), just update it to the given value. Ignore comments, where the key is mentioned(lines that start with #). The Key is case insensitive.

If the key is not set(disablepostprocessing and segmentstarttimeout), append key and value to the file. My function so far goes like this:

```
function setConfig( $file, $key, $value )
{
  (Get-Content $file) |
  Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "^"+$key+".=.+$", $key + " = " + $value } |
  Set-Content $file
}

setConfig divider.conf "Logentrytimeout" "180"
setConfig divider.conf "disablepostprocessing" "1"
setConfig divider.conf "segmentstarttimeout" "180"
```

- What is the correct regex?
- How do I check if there was a replacement?
- If there was no replacement: How can I append $key+" = "+$value to the file then?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming the `$key` you want to replace is always at the beginning of a line, and that it contains no special regex characters

```
function setConfig( $file, $key, $value ) {
    $content = Get-Content $file
    if ( $content -match "^$key\s*=" ) {
        $content -replace "^$key\s*=.*", "$key = $value" |
        Set-Content $file     
    } else {
        Add-Content $file "$key = $value"
    }
}

setConfig "divider.conf" "Logentrytimeout" "180"
```

If there is no replacement `$key = $value` will be appended to the file.

Answer (score 3):

Updated version of the functions above with some parametrisation and verbose output if required.

```
   Function Set-FileConfigurationValue()
{
    [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]   
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string][ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})] $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $Key,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $Value,
        [Switch] $ReplaceExistingValue,
        [Switch] $ReplaceOnly
    )

    $content = Get-Content -Path $Path
    $regreplace = $("(?<=$Key).*?=.*")
    $regValue = $("=" + $Value)
    if (([regex]::Match((Get-Content $Path),$regreplace)).success)
    {
        If ($ReplaceExistingValue)
        {
            Write-Verbose "Replacing configuration Key ""$Key"" in configuration file ""$Path"" with Value ""$Value"""
            (Get-Content -Path $Path) | Foreach-Object { [regex]::Replace($_,$regreplace,$regvalue) } | Set-Content $Path
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Warning "Key ""$Key"" found in configuration file ""$Path"". To replace this Value specify parameter ""ReplaceExistingValue"""
        }
    } 
    elseif (-not $ReplaceOnly) 
    {    
        Write-Verbose "Adding configuration Key ""$Key"" to configuration file ""$Path"" using Value ""$Value"""
        Add-Content -Path $Path -Value $("`n" + $Key + "=" + $Value)       
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Warning "Key ""$Key"" not found in configuration file ""$Path"" and parameter ""ReplaceOnly"" has been specified therefore no work done"
    }
}
```

Comment: Question, if a key/value exists but happens to be commented out, how do I either uncomment it, or throw an exception?  i am using this standalone, but how do i use it as an actual function with the parameters as strings, so i can use ..("./foo.cfg", "foo", "bar, baz")

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this:

```
function setConfig( $file, $key, $value )
{
  $regex = '^' + [regex]::escape($key) + '\s*=.+'
  $replace = "$key = $value"
  $old = get-content $file
  $new = $old -replace $regex,$replace 

  if (compare-object $old $new)
    {  
      Write-Host (compare-object $old $new |  ft -auto | out-string) -ForegroundColor Yellow
      $new | set-content $file
    }

    else {
           $replace | add-content $file
           Write-Host "$replace added to $file" -ForegroundColor Cyan
         }

}
```

Edit: added a replacement bell, and a not match whistle.

Answer (score 1):

Change the function to this:

```
function Set-Config( $file, $key, $value )
{
    $regreplace = $("(?<=$key).*?=.*")
    $regvalue = $(" = " + $value)
    if (([regex]::Match((Get-Content $file),$regreplace)).success) {
        (Get-Content $file) `
            |Foreach-Object { [regex]::Replace($_,$regreplace,$regvalue)
         } | Set-Content $file
    } else {
        Add-Content -Path $file -Value $("`n" + $key + " = " + $value)          
    }
}
```

Then when you call the function, use this format:

```
Set-Config -file "divider.conf" -key "Logentrytimeout" -value "180"
```

Edit:  I forgot your requirement of adding the line if it doesn't exist.  This will check for the `$key`, if it exists it will set its value to `$value`.  If it doesn't exist it will add `$key = $value` to the end of the file.  I also renamed the function to be more consistent with power shell naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

@CarlR Function it's for PowerShell Version 3. This it's the same adapted to **PowerShell Version 2**.

**EDIT: Changed regular expression to fix two bugs on Set-FileConfigurationValue:**

1. If you have one line like this:

   `; This is a Black line`

   And you try to do:

   `Set-FileConfigurationValue $configFile "Black" 20 -ReplaceExistingValue`

   You get one message about "Replacing" but nothing happens.
2. If you have two lines like these:

   filesTmp=50
   Tmp=50

   And you try to do:

   `Set-FileConfigurationValue $configFile "Tmp" 20 -ReplaceExistingValue`

   You get the two lines changed!

   filesTmp=20
   Tmp=20

**This is the final version:**

```
Function Set-FileConfigurationValue()
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        [string] $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $Key,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        [string]$Value,
        [Switch] $ReplaceExistingValue,
        [Switch] $ReplaceOnly
    )

    $regmatch= $("^($Key\s*=\s*)(.*)")
    $regreplace=$('${1}'+$Value)

    if ((Get-Content $Path) -match $regmatch)
    {
        If ($ReplaceExistingValue)
        {
            Write-Verbose "Replacing configuration Key ""$Key"" in configuration file ""$Path"" with Value ""$Value"""
            (Get-Content -Path $Path) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $regmatch,$regreplace } | Set-Content $Path
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Warning "Key ""$Key"" found in configuration file ""$Path"". To replace this Value specify parameter ""ReplaceExistingValue"""
        }
    } 
    elseif (-not $ReplaceOnly) 
    {    
        Write-Verbose "Adding configuration Key ""$Key"" to configuration file ""$Path"" using Value ""$Value"""
        Add-Content -Path $Path -Value $("`n" + $Key + "=" + $Value)       
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Warning "Key ""$Key"" not found in configuration file ""$Path"" and parameter ""ReplaceOnly"" has been specified therefore no work done"
    }
}
```

**I've also added a function to read from the config file**

```
Function Get-FileConfigurationValue()
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        [string] $Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $Key,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        [string]$Default=""
    )

    # Don't have spaces before key. 
    # To allow spaces, use "$Key\s*=\s*(.*)"
    $regKey = $("^$Key\s*=\s*(.*)")

    # Get only last time 
    $Value = Get-Content -Path $Path | Where {$_ -match $regKey} | Select-Object -last 1 | ForEach-Object { $matches[1] }
    if(!$Value) { $Value=$Default }

    Return $Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sed($filespec, $search, $replace)
{
    foreach ($file in gci -Recurse $filespec | ? { Select-String $search $_ -Quiet } )
    { 
    (gc $file) | 
     ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $search, $replace } | 
     Set-Content $file
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
sed ".\*.config" "intranet-" "intranetsvcs-"
```