# Saving edited file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to replace CodeFile to CodeBehind in all of my .aspx / aspx.cs files so far I have

```
$FileLocation = "F:\Code\trunk\Source\"

$FindAllItems = Get-ChildItem $FileLocation -Rec -Inc *.aspx,*.aspx.cs 

foreach ($file in $FindAllItems)
{

  foreach($line in @(Get-Content $file))
   {       
     if ($line -match  "CodeFile")
     {  
        Write-Host $line
        Write-Host "Renaming CodeFile to CodeBehind"
        $replacedLine = $line.Replace("CodeFile", "CodeBehind")
        Write-Host "edited line:" $replacedLine
        Write-Host "Saving change, naming" $file.fullname
     }         

   }    
}
Write-Host "Done"
```

how could i use the .save parameter in this situation or what is the best way to commit the edit?

Update:

After being told about Set-Content, I re-wrote the script, below is the working code.

```
$FileLocation = "F:\Code\trunk\Source\"

$FindAllItems = Get-ChildItem $FileLocation -Rec -Inc *ascx,*ascx.cs

foreach ($file in $FindAllItems)
{

(Get-Content $file) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "CodeFile", "CodeBehind"} | 
Set-Content $file

}
Write-Host "Done"
```

Comment: Why not use the global search & replace in Visual Studio or any other text editor which can perform searches on files?

Comment: There are certain files I don't want to search & replace, global would make the change, plus I wanted to make a script. This would have been an easy substitute, so if you want to put it up as an answer, you'd get an upvote from me, but Atique's post was what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662799/powershell-function-to-replace-or-add-lines-in-text-files) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875617/insert-content-into-text-file-in-powershell).
You can use [Set-Content](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176959.aspx) Cmdlet to commit changes. See example and explanation [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/01/17/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-replace-characters-in-a-text-file.aspx).